# Formik checkbox value not showing checked for a true value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, checkbox, formik

I'm using Formik with Material-UI/Stepper and I am having issues showing a checkbox that has a formik state value of true being checked.

Within my form, I am using the Material-UI stepper. The issue I am facing is that on page 1 of my form, I am using a checkbox (FormControlLabel API). When I click on the checkbox, the formik state  value for this is true but when I advance to the next page and then press the back button to return to page 1 where my checkbox is, the formik state value still maintains the true value but my checkbox is no longer checked.

Below is the code that I am using to render my checkbox but I'm not sure why the checkbox is not showing as checked for a true value?

I added the code `checked={field.checked}` within the `FormControlLabel` api but made no difference.

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  Checkbox,
  FormControl,
  FormControlLabel,
  FormGroup,
  FormLabel
} from '@material-ui/core';
import { useField, useFormikContext } from 'formik';

const CheckboxWrapper = ({
  name,
  label,
  legend,
  ...otherProps
}) => {
  const { setFieldValue } = useFormikContext();
  const [field, meta] = useField(name);

  const handleChange = evt => {
    const { checked } = evt.target;
    setFieldValue(name, checked);
  };

  const configCheckbox = {
    ...field,
    onChange: handleChange
  };

  const configFormControl = {};
  if (meta && meta.touched && meta.error) {
    configFormControl.error = true;
  }

  return (
    <FormControl {...configFormControl}>
      <FormLabel component="legend">{legend}</FormLabel>
      <FormGroup>
        <FormControlLabel
          control={<Checkbox {...configCheckbox} />}
          label={label}
          checked={field.checked}
        />
      </FormGroup>
    </FormControl>
  );
};

export default CheckboxWrapper;
```

The way I am calling the above within my actual form is as follows:

```
      <Checkbox 
        name="termsAgreement"
        label="I agree"
      />
```

where `name="termsAgreement"` is my formik initial state value.

Any help would be great.

Comment: I don't think `field.checked` will work here . The documentation says you need to pass an object to useField to access the checked property . try changing the argument you pass to useField as `{ name, type: 'checkbox' }` https://formik.org/docs/api/useField#fieldinputpropsvalue

Comment: @Shyam - the issue is not the formik state value, this is being set to true correctly, the issue is that I am losing the tick within the checkbox when I go forward a step and then go back a step. Tick no longer appears even though the value is still true.

Comment: what do you get when you console log the field.checked in your CheckboxWrapper ?

Comment: @Shyam - I get `undefined` but my formik name value where I am using my `<Checkboc/>`  is set to true. Any ideas how I can maintain a tick within my checkbox when it's formik state value is true?

Comment: @Shyam - found the fix. Pls see "Answer yur question"

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to use: `checked={field.value}` inorder to maintain the tick within the checkbox.

```
  return (
    <FormControl {...configFormControl}>
      <FormLabel component="legend">{legend}</FormLabel>
      <FormGroup>
        <FormControlLabel
          control={<Checkbox {...configCheckbox} />}
          label={label}
          checked={field.value}
        />
      </FormGroup>
    </FormControl>
  );
```